# XSLT Lookup Document returning multiple rows

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT 2 and am doing a document lookup, however it's returning in some case multiple rows

```
<xsl:value-of select="$LookupRegexReplace/Row[matches($seq4, @Key1, 'i')]/@RegexReplace"/>
```

How can I determine that multiple rows were returned, or is there a way to just return the first occurrence. I've tried the following but it didn't work?

```
<xsl:value-of select="$LookupRegexReplace/Row[matches($seq4, @Key1, 'i')]/@RegexReplace[1]"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="($LookupRegexReplace/Row[matches($seq4, @Key1, 'i')]/@RegexReplace)[1]"/>`